# Test program using big loop seems to hang partway through

Tags: c++, loops, freeze

I'm doing some research with my professor on the use of performance measuring software, and she recommended I write a sample program that just uses some big loops to do some function calls and floating point computations in order to get the hang of it.  Right now, it's running fine until it gets to i = 110, j = 99000, at which point it stops printing and just seems to hang or suspend operation.  I've tried using fflush( stdout ), but it didn't make a difference.  Do you have any thoughts on what might be causing this? (Just running it normally from the command line; compiler used is g++.)

```
#include <iostream>

double arrayFill(double a, double b){
     double c = (a+.5)*(b+.5);
     return c;
}

double bigLoop(double val){
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j){
            val += .5;
        }
    }
    return val;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    double **bigArray = new double*[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i){

        bigArray[i] = new double[10];

        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; ++j){
            double x = (double) i/1000;
            double y = (double) j/1000;
            bigArray[i%100][j%10]=arrayFill(x, y);
            bigArray[i%100][j%10]=bigLoop(bigArray[i%100][j%10]);
            if (j%1000 == 0){
                std::cout << bigArray[i%100][j%10] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
                std::cout << "j = " << j << std::endl;
                fflush( stdout );
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing `bigArray` with an invalid index.

You allocate only 100 elements for bigArray. `bigArray[i] = ...` is an undefined behavior for i >= 100. And in your program, `i` goes up to 99999.

Comment: Thanks - I thought I'd added the i%100 to all array accesses, but obviously I was wrong.  Do you have any idea why it didn't just crash or segfault?

Comment: I don't know. It can be anything (e.g. memory manager may go into an infinite loop because of the corrupted heap, or CPU jumps to some bogus address and executes garbage). If you have spare time to learn gdb and assembler, try running the program with a debugger and see where it hangs. :)